# How do I see what I changed to resolve a mercurial merge conflict?

Tags: merge, mercurial

I just merged changes from our maintenance branch into our development branch.  (We branch by cloning the mercurial repository, not with named branches.)  There were a few conflicts, so I had to manually edit a half a dozen lines or so to resolve the merge conflict.  No big deal.  But when I look at the merge commit, I see the bazillion lines from the entire stack of patches against one parent or the other, not the merge conflict.

How can I review just the conflict and its resolution?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the [MergeDiff](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergediffExtension) extension.

Comment: Quite possibly.  Would have to patch it up before I can tell.  https://bitbucket.org/wolever/hg-mergediff/issue/3/184-incompatibilities

Comment: After making the changes suggested in that ticket, mergediff displays some unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

`hg -n annotate` probably?

Or, better `annotate -n .. | grep 'hg tip --template "{rev}\n"'`. You know changeset number of mergeset, your edits will have this number (automerged string will get number of latest change)

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying, annotate the file at the merge and grep for lines that were changed... Yeah, that works, but it's relatively slow.  It'd need to at least be narrowed down to the set of files touched in the merge, annotating everything in the repository is super expensive.

Comment: blame -r N (only one revision's files used)?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to do this, I redo the merge with `ui.merge=internal:merge` so I get all the conflict markers. Then I diff it against the merge changeset. A bit clumsy, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hg diff` with the option `-c`:

> -c --change REV             change made by revision

**Tip:** use `--stat` to check only the files (with and without `-c`).